# parse deploy for cloud code not working

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Today I tried to upload some new files to parse cloud. As usual I performed the parse deploy command, but this time it didn't finish, it gets stuck in **uploading source files** notice, no error is shown so far.

I left it there for more than 30 minutes(usually it takes less than 2-4 minutes), and nothing..  What can I do to fix this? or where should I look for a log?  I'm using ver 1.4.2,  updated because I thought it would help.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried closing down the terminal/powershell and starting again?

Comment: Of course. Problem "partially solved"  Something was wrong between versions and stuff. between MAC and WIN Parse executable. I develop at home with MAC and office with WIN, I had to run PARSE from my MAC at home for it to work...  not working as of today in my WIN...  something happen there on PARSE side.

Answer (score 0):

You must **update** the CLI to its latest version (currently **2.1.2**) you can go to [Parse website](http://www.parse.com)

or if you still have problems I created a repo containign the files

https://github.com/JRSosa/ParseCLI